# Which tense is acceptable to use in titles?

Tags: tense, headlinese

What tense(s) is it acceptable to use in titles?

For example: In the the newspaper, or if I post on Facebook a video of someone that talked about me very nice in the video. Would I need to write in the title:

> This woman talks nice about me.

or

> This man is talking to me very nicely.

or

> This man talked to me very nicely.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would not use *talk* in reference to what someone says about you. Use *say*

> This man **is saying** very nice things about me.
>   This man **says** very nice things about me.

Present tense is fine. I would not use past tense since when someone views the video it will be in the present time.